# Boolean.FALSE or new Boolean(false)?

Tags: java, coding-style, boolean

I saw in the source of the Boolean class the following:

```
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
```

Hence, if I understand correctly the field `FALSE` in the `Boolean` class is a `Boolean` itself which has its `boolean` field set to `false`.

Now I wonder if the following two statements are truly equivalent.

```
Boolean myBool = new Boolean(false);
```

and

```
Boolean myBool = Boolean.FALSE;
```

I would assume that in the first case a new Boolean object is constructed and the myBool reference points to it, whereas in the second case we actually make a copy of the reference to the Boolean.FALSE object - is this correct?

And if so what does this difference *really* mean?

Last but not least the *actual* question: Which of the two options should I prefer and why?

Comment: You should use `Boolean.FALSE`. This conforms to the future updates which JDK may be having.

Comment: And also `Boolean.valueOf()` is preferrable to `new Boolean()` in general.

Comment: Neither. Use `false` and let the compiler sort it out via autoboxing.

Comment: @EJP I don't like that so much. I prefer things to be as *explicit* as possible. Implicit things like autoboxing/unboxing require more thinking for a person who reads the code. I usually try to write code which is as readable and understandable as possible, even for a person who doesn't know much about java and its quirks... but that's just a personal style choice...

Comment: Your response reminds me of [this Gary Larson cartoon](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6EOAz4NB0j1enGBsR7rA4fr8uFY1i1Kbmapdzao8ISGLZdDKH). Everybody has to draw a line somewhere, and that line is going to differ for different people. @EJP's advice seems fine to me, understanding autoboxing is a basic survival skill. there is a noise factor to consider vs. explicitness.

Comment: @NathanHughes I agree. I said its a personal style choice. In my company people get transferred a lot from one large project to another. C++, C#, Javascript, sql-dialcets, bash, propietary eso-langs from the 90s, etc. I don't expect fluency in all that. I try to write code for DAUs. The *new guy* should be able to pick up quickly even if he has no Java-bg but rather general and solid OO-knowledge. He should be able to focus on the business logic and move to the C# project in a few month without having to read a book first. You find  `Boolean myBool = Boolean.FALSE;` noisy? Btw.: nice cartoon!

Answer (score 5):

The difference:

```
Boolean.FALSE == Boolean.FALSE
```

(boolean) true

```
new Boolean(false) == new Boolean(false)
```

(boolean) false

---

Use

```
Boolean myBool = false;
```

and let autoboxing handle it.

Answer (score 3):

You should use Boolean.FALSE rather than creating a new Object on heap, because it's unnecessary. We should use this static final Object it the memory and even it's faster to access this.

And yes you are correct that :

> first case a new Boolean object is constructed and the myBool
>   reference points to it

But in second case we just point to existing object.

And your another question while we have Boolean.FALSE why we have the option to **new Boolean(false)**  the reason is that it's a constructor. Suppose that you have a primitive boolean variable x and you don't know it's value whether it's true or false and you want a corresponding Boolean Object, than this constructor will be used to pass that primitive boolean variable x to get Boolean object.

Comment: Wouldn't in that case Keppil's comment apply and one should rather use Boolean.valueOf()?

Comment: Yes it's better to use Boolean.valueOf() over constructor.

Comment: @Keppil ok. then as a follow up: I don't get why would one ever want a new Boolean object rather than always let it point to either Boolean.FALSE (Boolean.TRUE) respectively. From what I see `valueOf` actually also does that. So is there *any* use case where one would really to create a new Boolean object?

Comment: @dingalapadum: Not any practical case that I can think of, no. There might exist a corner case where you want the same value but `==` comparison to return false, but that seems far-fetched.